# Cannot find the declaration of element 'ehcache'

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I am implementing url caching in my web application. I have error in ehcache.xml file while run time. I am using spring 2.5 jar file.

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false"
    monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true" maxBytesLocalOnHeap="2m"
    maxBytesLocalOffHeap="2m" maxBytesLocalDisk="2m">


    <defaultCache eternal="false" maxElementsInMemory="1000"
        overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" timeToIdleSeconds="0"
        timeToLiveSeconds="600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

    <cache name="videoItemsCache" eternal="false"
        maxElementsInMemory="1000" timeToIdleSeconds="1200" timeToLiveSeconds="1200"
        overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" />

</ehcache>
```

Error is :

```
ERROR: VideoClubPortal 27-Sep-2012 11:53 context.ContextLoader Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 6 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/ehcache.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 31; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ehcache'.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:404)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:422)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:352)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 31; cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ehcache'.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:387)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:321)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1920)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:709)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:602)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3080)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:899)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:819)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:748)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:239)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
```

Please any one help me.

Comment: Please add spring configuration, and check echache.xml can be found in classpath. If you use web application, be sure echache.xml can be found in WEB-INF/classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this, this I am using in my project

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:ehcache="http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springmodules.org/schema/ehcache http://www.springmodules.org/schema/cache/springmodules-ehcache.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <ehcache:config configLocation="classpath:ehcache.xml" />

    <ehcache:proxy id="saleDAO" refId="saleDAOTarget">
        <ehcache:caching cacheName="saleCache" methodName="findAll"/>
        <ehcache:flushing cacheNames="saleCache" methodName="saveSaleRecord" when="after"/>
    </ehcache:proxy>

    <bean id="saleDAOTarget" class="byteco.de.spring.SaleDAOImpl">
        <property name="namedParameterJdbcTemplate" ref="jdbcTemplate"></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="datasource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
        <property name="username" value="root"/>
        <property name="password" value="password"/>
        <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/demo"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
        <constructor-arg type="javax.sql.DataSource" ref="datasource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<ehcache>
    <defaultCache
            maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"/>
    <cache name="contactCache" maxElementsInMemory="500" eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"/>
</ehcache>
```

Answer (score 5):

xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd"

this location must be a absolute path

like this： ...Location="classpath:/yourPathInProject/ehcache.xml"

before this ,you need to download the ehcache.xml from  http://www.ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd
and put it in your path .

Comment: and this answer will run ehcache with an offline enviroment

Answer (score 2):

In case of ehcache 3.x you may refer following template for ehcache.xml:

```
    <config
    xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
    xmlns='http://www.ehcache.org/v3'
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.ehcache.org/v3 http://www.ehcache.org/schema/ehcache-core-3.0.xsd">

  <cache alias="ready-cache">
    <key-type>java.lang.Long</key-type>
    <value-type>com.pany.domain.Product</value-type>
    <loader-writer>
      <class>com.pany.ehcache.integration.ProductCacheLoaderWriter</class>
    </loader-writer>
    <heap unit="entries">100</heap>
  </cache>

</config>
```

Basically the reference to ehcache's xsd is updated as per the above xsd declaration.
For further details on how to use different XML options for ehcache 3.x , please refer [ehcache documentation for JSR](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/3.0/107.html)