# Hibernate application can not start if there is no network

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am working on an applicaton and I encounter a problem related with hibernate ehcache.

When there is no network the application that I am working on can not start. I've checked Tomcat logs and I saw the exception below.

Why is the exception below is thrown? Also if there is no problem with network,i don't encounter with a problem.

Regards

```
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 50; White spaces are required between publicId and systemId.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:198)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:441)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1388)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanExternalID(XMLScanner.java:1000)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.scanDoctypeDecl(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:647)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:931)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:629)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaParsingConfig.parse(SchemaParsingConfig.java:685)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.opti.SchemaDOMParser.parse(SchemaDOMParser.java:530)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2155)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:562)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:588)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.findSchemaGrammar(XMLSchemaValidator.java:2448)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:1767)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.emptyElement(XMLSchemaValidator.java:761)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2717)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:489)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:237)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:300)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
... 27 more
```

The config can be found below.

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:ehcache="http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd 
                       http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring http://ehcache-spring-annotations.googlecode.com/svn/schema/ehcache-spring/ehcache-spring-1.1.xsd">
```

Comment: If your application should work without network, i suppose it is a jar file. Are you using maven shade plugin or something similar to make that file?

Answer (score 2):

Could you post header of your config (e.g. ehcache.xml)?

I remember I had problem with ehcache trying to access the Internet (I'm not sure if it's your case, but probably it's worth to take a shoot). But I solved it by adding updateCheck="false" to my ehcache.xml config (it disables auto updating):

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="false">
```

P.S.

Maybe this thread [White spaces are required between publicId and systemId](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514158/white-spaces-are-required-between-publicid-and-systemid) could give you a hint about the solution.

P.P.S. 
Maybe your application can't access ehcache.xsd?
[How to use local xsd for EhCache with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266339/how-to-use-local-xsd-for-ehcache-with-spring)

[Cannot find the declaration of element 'ehcache'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615795/cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-ehcache)

EDIT

It looks like your application can not find ehcache.xsd file. So, try solution in this thread: [Cannot find the declaration of element 'ehcache'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12615795/cannot-find-the-declaration-of-element-ehcache)

Comment: This problem only occurs when there is no network ,if there is network the application can start successfully.Is it possible to make the application start in an no network condition?

Answer (score 1):

The exception doesn't make sense to me, but I've experienced problems with DTD/XSD referenced from the Web. Without Internet access, the DTD/XSD cannot be retrieved, leading to various errors.